# Calculate group mean while excluding current observation using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Using `dplyr` (preferably), I am trying to calculate the group mean for each observation while excluding that observation from the group.

It seems that this should be doable with a combination of `rowwise()` and `group_by()`, but both functions cannot be used simultaneously.

Given this data frame:

```
df <- data_frame(grouping = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 3),
                 value = 1:15) %>%
  arrange(grouping)
df
#> Source: local data frame [15 x 2]
#> 
#>    grouping value
#>       (chr) (int)
#> 1         A     1
#> 2         A     6
#> 3         A    11
#> 4         B     2
#> 5         B     7
#> 6         B    12
#> 7         C     3
#> 8         C     8
#> 9         C    13
#> 10        D     4
#> 11        D     9
#> 12        D    14
#> 13        E     5
#> 14        E    10
#> 15        E    15
```

I'd like to get the group mean for each observation with that observation excluded from the group, resulting in:

```
#>    grouping value special_mean
#>       (chr) (int)
#> 1         A     1          8.5  # i.e. (6 + 11) / 2
#> 2         A     6            6  # i.e. (1 + 11) / 2
#> 3         A    11          3.5  # i.e. (1 + 6) / 2
#> 4         B     2          9.5
#> 5         B     7            7
#> 6         B    12          4.5
#> 7         C     3          ...
```

I've attempted nesting `rowwise()` inside a function called by `do()`, but haven't gotten it to work, along these lines:

```
special_avg <- function(chunk) {
  chunk %>%
    rowwise() #%>%
    # filter or something...?
}

df %>%
  group_by(grouping) %>%
  do(special_avg(.))
```

Comment: At the risk of being really "quick and dirty", this may work for you (but isn't necessarily a general approach) `df %>% group_by(grouping) %>% mutate(avg = (sum(value)-value)/(n()-1))`

Comment: If you need a special function, `combn` can be useful `df %>% group_by(grouping) %>% mutate(avg = combn(value, n()-1, FUN=mean))`

Comment: Ooh, had never seen `combn()` before.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for introducing `combn` but after playing with it trying to solve [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450278/summarize-with-dplyr-other-then-groups/36463525#36463525) I found out that you have to reverse the vector in order to omit the current observation `combn(rev(value), n()-1, FUN = mean)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need to define a custom function, instead we could simply sum all elements of the group, subtract the current value, and divide by number of elements per group minus `1`.

```
df %>% group_by(grouping) %>%
        mutate(special_mean = (sum(value) - value)/(n()-1))
#   grouping value special_mean
#      (chr) (int)        (dbl)
#1         A     1          8.5
#2         A     6          6.0
#3         A    11          3.5
#4         B     2          9.5
#5         B     7          7.0
```

Comment: Nice—I like the math-based approach way better than futzing around with the data and extra functions. I replaced the group size with `(n() - 1)` so it's more dynamic.

Comment: nice, but what if we want to use another function, say `max`?

Comment: @jlesuffleur Perhaps, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68920876/3817004) may answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this old question just by chance and I wondered if there is a *general solution* which would work for other aggregation functions besides `mean()` as well, e.g., `max()` as requested [by jlesuffleur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858876/calculate-group-mean-while-excluding-current-observation-using-dplyr#comment98652219_35859197) or `median()`.

The idea is to omit the actual row from computing the aggregate by looping over the rows within the actual group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grouping) %>% 
  mutate(special_mean = sapply(1:n(), function(i) mean(value[-i])))
```

> ```
>    grouping value special_mean
>    <chr>    <int>        <dbl>
>  1 A            1          8.5
>  2 A            6          6  
>  3 A           11          3.5
>  4 B            2          9.5
>  5 B            7          7  
> ...
> ```

This will work for `max()` as well

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grouping) %>% 
  mutate(special_max = sapply(1:n(), \(i) max(value[-i])))
```

> ```
>    grouping value special_max
>    <chr>    <int>       <int>
>  1 A            1          11
>  2 A            6          11
>  3 A           11           6
>  4 B            2          12
>  5 B            7          12
>  6 B           12           7
> ...
> ```

For the sake of completeness, here is also a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, special_mean := sapply(1:.N, function(i) mean(value[-i])), by = grouping][]
```

Comment: Nice with a more general solution, but perhaps consider to add a `data.table` solution also for the "special case" of `mean` (`df[, mean2 := (sum(value) - value) / (.N - 1), by = grouping]`) (it will be a good dupe-target for leave-one-out stuff). Cheers