# How to compute a leave one out average using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, dplyr

Hi I am trying to find a leave one out average of a variable in all rows using `dplyr`. Since `dplyr` provides a convenient function called `row_number()`, I thought I could use it like this:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  tbl_df %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length) %>%
  mutate(loo_avg=mean(Sepal.Length[-row_number()]))  # leave one out average
```

But this returns a result like this:

```
Source: local data frame [150 x 2]

   Sepal.Length loo_avg
          (dbl)   (dbl)
1           5.1     NaN
2           4.9     NaN
3           4.7     NaN
4           4.6     NaN
5           5.0     NaN
6           5.4     NaN
7           4.6     NaN
8           5.0     NaN
9           4.4     NaN
10          4.9     NaN
..          ...     ...
```

How do you fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858876/calculate-group-mean-while-excluding-current-observation-using-dplyr/35859197#35859197

Comment: @mtoto That is pretty neat! . But...what if I want to use more complicated function than the average? I was looking if there is a way that uses subsetting..

Comment: see akrun's comment in the linked question.

Comment: Deleted my answer. akrun's on the linked question is superior, and also sticks to the `dplyr` tag.